# hive: cast array<struct<score:double,name:string>> into map<string,double>

Tags: hadoop, casting, hive

I have a hive table that has a primary key "id" and an array of structs with a string "name", and a double "score"

I want to create a new table that preserves the primary key, and casts the array into a map.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not a duplicate of this? (I know your question was earlier, but that one actually has an answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863171/hive-cast-arraystructkeystring-valuearraystring-into-mapstring-arrays