# Join tables with almost same schema in hive

Tags: sql, arrays, dictionary, hive, hiveql

I have table A with schema

```
name            string                                      
address         string                                      
timezone        string                                      
one_key_value   map<string,array<string>>                       
two_key_value   map<string,array<string>>
```

and table B with schema

```
name            string                                      
address         string                                      
timezone        string                                      
one_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>                    
two_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>
```

I'm trying to do a union all

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B) tmp;
```

get an error

```
FAILED: SemanticException Schema of both sides of union should match.
```

Is there a way to fix this as they are almost similar, it's just that for table B the values are in an array.

Comment: No for this to work they should have same datatype. What are you trying to achieve here using union SQL?

Comment: @rs.   Both the tables have same data so I'm trying to merge them to create a view

Comment: You will need to cast or convert both key_value columns to one datatype.

Comment: I think you need first use  explode(array) to covert it to map.check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897984/hive-cast-arraystructscoredouble-namestring-into-mapstring-double)

Answer (score 1):

Explode `map` column and assemble `array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>`, so it will be the same type as in table_b, this should work as of Hive version 1.3.0:

```
select * from
(
select s.name, s.address, s.timezone, 
       --get arrays array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>
       collect_set(mystruct1) as one_key_value,
       collect_set(mystruct2) as two_key_value
  from
(
select a.*, 
       --get structs struct<key:string,value:array<string>
       named_struct('key',k1.key, 'value', k1.value) mystruct1,
       named_struct('key',k2.key, 'value', k2.value) mystruct2
  from table_a a
       --explode maps, get key:string, value:array<string>
       lateral view outer explode(one_key_value) k1 key,value     
       lateral view outer explode(two_key_value) k2 key,value  
)s
group by s.name, s.address, s.timezone
) table_a

UNION ALL

select * from table_b
;
```

Also there is Brickhouse `collect` UDF for previous versions of Hive:

```
add jar /path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

 select * from
    (
    select s.name, s.address, s.timezone, 
           --get arrays array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>
           collect(mystruct1) as one_key_value,
           collect(mystruct2) as two_key_value
      from
    (
    select a.*, 
           --get structs struct<key:string,value:array<string>
           named_struct('key',k1.key, 'value', k1.value) mystruct1,
           named_struct('key',k2.key, 'value', k2.value) mystruct2
      from table_a a
           --explode maps, get key:string, value:array<string>
           lateral view outer explode(one_key_value) k1 key,value     
           lateral view outer explode(two_key_value) k2 key,value  
    )s
    group by s.name, s.address, s.timezone
    ) table_a

    UNION ALL

    select * from table_b
    ;
```

Comment: I still get an error, it could be because the table_b is partitioned by name and address. Any way to include that for table_a ?

Comment: No, partitioning does not matter, the number of columns, type and positions in both parts of UNION ALL should be the same. Do not use select *, name columns instead. Does my subquery works and produces what expected? I did not test it. Post some data example, I will try to debug

Comment: I just realized this is exploding the table and creating a new row for each value. I just need a single row for a key and all it's value. Any idea what changes I should make to this? Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnConstantine  `collect_set()` + `group by` should should do

Comment: Where should I add group by? I tried adding it but get an error, could you please edit your code. Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnConstantine If you are not selecting some struct elements in the same query, only collect_set(), s.name, s.address, s.timezone group by s.name, s.address, s.timezone - it should be fine. Which query are you using

Comment: SELECT 
name, address, timezone,
map(k1,v1) AS ad_request_key_value, 
map(k2,v2) AS matched_key_value
FROM table_a 
lateral view inline(ad_request_key_value) t1 as k1,v1
lateral view inline(matched_key_value) t2 as k2,v2

Comment: I am using the above query.

Comment: @JohnConstantine  You are selecting exploded rows produced by inline. What you need is to collect array + group by. map() - is not array yet and does not collect rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183204/discussion-between-john-constantine-and-leftjoin).