# hive: cast array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>> into map<string,array<string>>

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table like

```
name            string                                      
address         string                                      
timezone        string                                      
one_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>                    
two_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>
```

and want to convert it to

```
name            string                                      
address         string                                      
timezone        string                                      
one_key_value   map<string,array<string>>                       
two_key_value   map<string,array<string>>
```

There is `explode(array)` but doesn't really return the entire table in the format I want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lateral view` with `inline` and `map` the resulting keys and values.

```
select name,address,timezone,map(k1,v1),map(k2,v2)
from tbl 
lateral view inline(one_key_value) t1 as k1,v1
lateral view inline(two_key_value) t1 as k2,v2
```

Comment: Is there a way to not specify column names and just do * as there are more than 50 columns.

Comment: you can do it in `select`, but note you will get the original and transformed columns in that case.

Comment: How can I add a where statement to this, like where date='2018-10-10'

Comment: you can use it at the end..after `lateral view`

Comment: I just realized this is exploding the table and creating a new row for each value. I just need a single row for a key and all it's value. Any idea what changes I should make to this? Thanks :)